# MySQL Delete Row Based On Column Name

Tags: mysql, sql

Table2 has a column with values containing column names in table1. I want to remove any entries in table2 where the actual column name in table1 does not exist. This is the general idea but apparently isn't the proper approach so how can it be done?

```
DELETE FROM table2 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT 
ID 
FROM table2 
WHERE FormID = 2 
AND FieldName NOT IN (SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' 
AND TABLE_NAME =  'table1'))
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: you have error :.?   .. what's the problem  with your query?

Comment: @Barmar How is this in any way a duplicate? The other is about deleting from one table based on content of another but this question is how to delete from one table based on an actual column name from another. Not even close to the same thing.

Comment: You're trying to delete from `table2`, and the `WHERE ID IN` subquery uses `table2`. That's not allowed in MySQL, and the other question explains how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be you can't delete rows  from the same table you are selecti so try using a subquery instead of a IN clause

```
DELETE table2 FROM table2 
INNER JOIN  (
   SELECT ID 
    FROM table2 
    WHERE FormID = 2 
    AND FieldName NOT IN (
        SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' 
        AND TABLE_NAME =  'table1'
      )
) t on t.ID = table2.ID
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks good, making more sense than my original query, and I'll check it out tomorrow to be sure I didn't introduce errors when pasting it in and putting the actual values back in as a quick test gives a syntax error.

Comment: @DonP  .. let me know if the asnwer  is right or if you have some error

Comment: I’m more awake now but still getting the syntax error on line 2. Running the two selects together without the rest does give the expected ID value but the DELETE has no WHERE.

Comment: When you use a join in a `DELETE` query, you need to specify the table that you're deleting from: `DELETE table2 FROM table2 ...`

Comment: answer  updated .. delete table from table

Comment: @Barmar   .. thanks for the suggestion ..

Comment: @DonP   . the ON clause in a JOIN is the where clause  ..

Comment: Works great now, thank you!